# What is type of graphql refetch when passing as props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am passing graphql `refetch` to component as props, but I am not sure what should be the type?

```
const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(gqlquery, {
        variables: { where: { id: id } },
    });
```

```
  <myinfo
     loading={loading}
     data={data}
     refetch={refetch}
   />
```

```
export const myinfo= ({
    refetch,
    loading,
    data,
}: myinfoProps) => {}
```

```
type myinfoProps= {
    refetch?: any;
    loading: boolean;
    data: {}
};
```

I want to remove `any` from  `refetch?: any;` what should be there instead of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, the type of [`refetch`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) is :

```
 type myinfoProps= {
    refetch?: (options: { throwOnError: boolean, cancelRefetch: boolean }) => Promise<UseQueryResult>;
    loading: boolean;
    data: {}
};
```

While calling you will have to check if it is defined or not since it is an optional property :

```
export const myinfo= ({
    refetch,
    loading,
    data,
}: myinfoProps) => {
  if(refetch){
         refetch(/* parameters */);
    }

}
```

Comment: so what I have supposed to while calling  `refetch();`

Comment: Please see updated answer. What you pass in params depends on the configuration you want

Comment: wrote this ```if (refetch){refetch({throwOnError: true,cancelRefetch: false,});}```

Comment: and ```refetch?: (options: {throwOnError: boolean;cancelRefetch: boolean;}) => Promise<UseQueryResult>;```   `UseQueryResult` data format getting from query result. gives ` Type '{ throwOnError: boolean; cancelRefetch: boolean; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<{ where: { id: string; }; }>'.`